# How can I recover my Gmail account when I remember the password, not the username?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I have a Gmail account that I haven't used in ages so I've forgotten the login name I used to sign up with. I've forgotten the recovery e-mail address setup on the account but I can remember my password.

How can I find out the username?

Whenever I go to http://gmail.com I just get the "Create New Account" page. There's no option "I've already got an account, what's my username?".

Once I have that I can use the password recovery options.

I need to have a Gmail account for Google Talk but don't really want to create another account unless I really have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Google Support you can use the recovery link on this page: [Recovering sign-in information](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=27443)

[image: Forgot your username feature]

From here, you should try with all accounts you are associated with to see what accounts are linked. (Assuming you remember all email accounts used apart from the one you forgot). It is sort of hit and miss but it has worked for me on two separate occasions.

You should get an email similar to the following.

> Your recovery address, phwd@gmail.com, is associated with:
>
> xxxx@gmail.com
>    xxxx@gmail.com
>    xxxx@gmail.com
>    xxxx@gmail.com
>    xxxx@gmail.com
>
> To sign in, visit the link below.
>
> http://www.google.com/accounts/
>
> If you've received this mail in error, it's likely that another user
>   entered your email address by mistake while trying to recall their
>   username. If you didn't initiate the request, you don't need to take
>   any further action and can safely disregard this email.
>
> If clicking the link above does not work, copy and paste the URL in a
>   new browser window instead.
>
> Thank you for using Google.
>
> For questions or concerns regarding your account, please visit the
>   Google Accounts FAQ at http://www.google.com/support/accounts/.
>
> This is a post-only mailing.  Replies to this message are not
>   monitored or answered.

As seen above it works for multiple accounts. So any account that has phwd@gmail.com listed is brought up in the list.

Additionally you can search your email accounts for the following subject line

> Your Gmail address has been created

This will bring up (if you didn't delete it), the confirmation email messages of all Gmail accounts you used the current account as a recovery point. *Although, based on "used in ages" I am not sure how far back Google used to send out this message.*

Answer (score 3):

This page only appears if you are logged into another Google site (such as Google+). Simply log out of this site or use an incognito/private browsing tab to get the regular login page. From there you can go to "can't access my account" and then "forgotten my username" to get it sent to your recovery address.